# Makefile in Linux error: *** No rule to make target `all'. Stop

Tags: linux, apache, makefile

I'm installing Apache on my Linux server RedHat 6.4.
I follow the following guide: http://squirrelmail.org/docs/admin/admin-3.html

When executing the make file, i got the following error:

```
Making all in srclib
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.20/srclib'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `all'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.20/srclib'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Can you please suggest how I can proceed further?

Comment: In which step you are getting the error?

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using the system packages?

Comment: Check the Makefile in /usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.20/srclib, if it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SquirrelMail is in the epel.repo https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

```
yum install epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

```
yum install squirrelmail
```

---

Comment: hi Larsen...actually, my server cannot go to internet...It is prohibited :( Hence I have to install it from source code :( But it is getting stuck in Apache installation

Answer (score 0):

Im facing this recently and manage to solved it.. below is the solution i made.

go to srclib folder in httpd

create new file as "Makefile.in"

the content will be like this

```
BUILD_SUBDIRS = $(AP_BUILD_SRCLIB_DIRS)
CLEAN_SUBDIRS = $(AP_CLEAN_SRCLIB_DIRS)

include $(top_builddir)/build/rules.mk
```

and save it.

Now you can run make command in httpd folder